# QUiLoader vs QFormBuilder

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-designer

I am trying to construct a widged based on a ui file (produced by qt designer) on runtime.

I found 2 classes that seem to do the job:
[QUiLoader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html#details)
[QFormBuilder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformbuilder.html#details)

They both have very similar API. Which one should I use, which one is more performant or modern and why are there two classes in the first place?

Comment: Why didn't you just read the description provided by the documention? It seems perfectly clear: "The QFormBuilder class is typically used by custom components and applications that embed Qt Designer. Standalone applications that need to dynamically generate user interfaces at run-time use the QUiLoader class, found in the QtUiTools module".

Comment: I thought plugins would take care of custom widget creation. And it seems like both support plugins. I still dont get it why a QFormBuilder exists? A (not-overloaded) QUiLoader does the same as a QFormBuilder, right? QUiLoader just supports overloading to replace certain widget by custom ones, but by default it does the same as the other?